# Pylint Consider using ternary

Tags: python, pylint

How to transpose this line of code?

```
    return ((min_bb is None and max_bb is None)
            or min_bb <= hand["BB"] <= max_bb)
```

The error is the following:
**R: 37, 4: Consider using ternary (max_bb is None if min_bb is None else min_bb <
= hand['BB'] <= max_bb) (consider-using-ternary)**

Thank you

Comment: You have the answer in the error message.

Comment: The message (pylint does not really give errors) tells you exactly what is being suggested to use instead. I think your version is clearer overall, but you should think about what will happen if one of the values is None and the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the idea is that when `min_bb` is None then there is no restriction on how low `hand['BB']` may be, and similarly on the other end.

This is a little more complex than it sounds, and I think it's better to consider each side of the comparison separately:

```
return (min_bb is None or min_bb <= hand["BB"]) and (max_bb is None or hand["BB"] <= max_bb)
```

It's a little less DRY (`hand["BB"]` is repeated) but I think it's clearer, and in particular it's obvious what happens when one of the bounds values is None and the other isn't.